# How can I prevent R from automatically converting æ to a?

Tags: r, special-characters

In short, R is now converting æ's to a's:

```
> chars = c("æ", "a")
> chars[1] == chars[2]
[1] TRUE
```

I need R to recognise æ. Is there any way to do this? As far as I can tell I have never had any similar trouble with other special characters (and I have had *much* more obscure characters than æ). (I apologise if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find any other questions along these lines.) Thanks!

Comment: It works fine with me and gives false. Can you give specifications on the environment you are working on? Sys.getlocale()

Comment: LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Traditional)_Hong Kong SAR.950;LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Traditional)_Hong Kong SAR.950;LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Traditional)_Hong Kong SAR.950;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Chinese (Traditional)_Hong Kong SAR.950. What could I change it to that would give the desired result?

Comment: Check out `?Sys.setlocale`

Comment: I've tried the German in the example as well as French - both of these work with æ but give me trouble with the combining tilde instead. Is there any locale (Windows) that would work with any utf-8 character?

Comment: What happens when you try `charToRaw( c("æa"))`? Does it give you the same two bytes?

Comment: On my original locale, yes!